# box2d var access  from diff class in iphone using c++

Tags: iphone

i have a car.h

now inside the car.h i did

```
float cc;
void Step(Settings* settings)
    {


        Test::Step(settings);


    cc=m_rightWheel->GetWorldCenter().x;// cc hold wheel value i needs this in other class

    }
```

now i want to access the **value of cc** in other class , so i did

```
// in VC.h
Car car;

// in VC.m

NSLog(@"car is moving at %f",car.cc );// not working
NSLog(@"car is moving at %f",car->cc );// not working
```

how to get the value of cc here ??

Comment: `**cc=m_rightWheel->GetWorldCenter().x` looks weird. Remove the `**`

Comment: got it , just calling cc will work damn i am so stupid :(

Comment: I added my answer below so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`**cc=m_rightWheel->GetWorldCenter().x` looks weird. Remove the `**`.

Comment: hahaha  .. well is that ans???  :) that ** was bold character code (provided by stack overflow only )